# Memset struct variables separately vs memset entire struct, which is faster?

Tags: c, memset

Say I have a structure like this:

```
struct tmp {
    unsigned char arr1[10];
    unsigned char arr2[10];
    int  i1;
    int  i2;
    unsigned char arr3[10];
    unsigned char arr4[10];
};
```

Which of these would be faster?

(1) Memset entire struct to 0 and then fill members as:

```
struct tmp t1;
memset(&t1, 0, sizeof(struct tmp));

t1.i1 = 10;
t1.i2 = 20;
memcpy(t1.arr1, "ab", sizeof("ab"));
// arr2, arr3 and arr4 will be filled later.
```

OR

(2) Memset separate variables:

```
struct tmp t1;
t1.i1 = 10;
t1.i2 = 20;
memcpy(t1.arr1, "ab", sizeof("ab"));

memset(t1.arr2, 0, sizeof(t1.arr2); // will be filled later
memset(t2.arr3, 0, sizeof(t1.arr3); // will be filled later
memset(t2.arr4, 0, sizeof(t1.arr4); // will be filled later
```

Just in terms of performance, is multiple calls to memset faster (on separate members of a structure) faster/slower than a single call to memset (on the entire structure).

Comment: One global memset is slightly faster (unless you have hundreds on non-array fields), but you might also consider just `t1.arr[0] = '\0';`. If the memory image is saved, a global memset is need for alignment of field offsets, where otherwise garbage would be shown..

Comment: Null terminator is not required in my case since its network bytes I'm dealing with. Memory image is not being saved, but yes it could be garbage that can be read by some other function.

Comment: `sizeof("ab")` counts the null terminator though

Comment: If the initialization needs to happen only once, the fastest is to do it at compile-time with a definition like `struct tmp t1 = { .i1 = 10, .i2 = 20, .arr1 = { 'a', 'b' } };`. Most compilers would then place t1 in an initialized data section.

Comment: @Jens I see, thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

It isn't really meaningful to discuss this without a specific system in mind, nor is it fruitful to ponder these things unless you actually have a performance bottlneck. I can give it a try still.

For a "general computer", you would have to consider:

- **Aligned access**
  Accessing a chunk of data in one go is usually better. In case of potential misalignment, the overhead code to deal with that is roughly the same no matter how large the data is. Assuming theoretically that all access in this code happens to be misaligned, then 1 memset call is better than 3.

  Also, we can assume that the first item of a struct is aligned, but we cannot assume that for any individual member inside the struct. The linker will allocate the struct at an aligned address, then potentially add padding anywhere inside it to compensate for misalignment.

  Your struct has been declared without any consideration about alignment, so this will be an issue here - the compiler will insert lots of padding.

  (On the other hand, a memset on the whole struct will also overwrite padding bytes, which is a tiny bit of overhead code.)
- **Data cache use**
  Accessing an area of adjacent memory from top to bottom is much more "cache-friendly" than accessing fragments of it from multiple places in your code. Subsequent access of contiguous memory means that the computer can load a lot of data into cache, instead of fetching it from RAM, which is slower.
- **Instruction cache use and branch prediction**
  Not very relevant in this case, since the code is basically just doing raw copies and doing so branch-free.
- **The amount of machine instructions generated**
  This is always a good, rough indication of how fast the code is. Obviously some instructions are a lot slower than others etc, but less instructions very often means faster code. Dissassembling your two functions with gcc x86_64 -O3 then I get this:

  ```
  func1:
      movabs  rax, 85899345930
      pxor    xmm0, xmm0
      movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi+16], xmm0
      mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+20], rax
      mov     eax, 25185
      movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
      movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi+32], xmm0
      mov     WORD PTR [rdi], ax
      ret

  func2:
      movabs  rax, 85899345930
      xor     edx, edx
      xor     ecx, ecx
      xor     esi, esi
      mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+20], rax
      mov     eax, 25185
      mov     WORD PTR [rdi], ax
      mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+2], 0
      mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+10], 0
      mov     WORD PTR [rdi+18], dx
      mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+28], 0
      mov     WORD PTR [rdi+36], cx
      mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+38], 0
      mov     WORD PTR [rdi+46], si
      ret
  ```

  This is a pretty good indication that the former code is more efficient, and it should also be more data cache-friendly, so it would surprise me if (1) isn't significantly faster.

Also note that if you declared this struct with static storage duration, you would "outsource" the zero-out to the CRT part of the program setting `.bss` and getting executed before main() is even called. Then none of these memset would be needed. At the expensive of slightly slower start-up, but a faster program overall.

Comment: This for a "generic computer", x86 like. If you'd done the same exercise on a low-end 8 bit MCU, then only the machine code would matter. Alignment would be a non-issue and cache wouldn't be available.

Comment: I see, thank you for all this info. I guess optimising this will not be as meaningful as optimising actual algorithm.